# cons to using flask-sqlalchemy pickletype

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have data that looks something like this:

```
projects = [
    {
        'title': 'Project A',
        'point_of_contact': {'name': 'Johnny', 'org': 'Box'},
        'overrides': [4, 7, 99, 42],
        'tier_mapping': {1: 2000, 2: 4000, 3: 8000, 4: 12000},
        'milestones': [{'year': 2014, 'achievement': 'Model development'}, {'year': 2014, 'achievement': 'Model approved by board'}]
    },
    {
        'title': 'Project B',
        ...
    }
```

As you can tell there's no obvious structure. I'm looking to add this to my sql-backed flask web application. The easiest option would be to create a single table using flask-sqlalchemy:

```
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.PickleType)
```

Another option would be to create a table for each iterative item and map that to its respective `Project`. For example, creating a relationship between a project and its overrides may look like this:

```
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    overrides = db.relationship('Override', backref='mapped_project', lazy='dynamic')

class Override(dn.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    override = db.Column(db.Integer)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'))
```

My question is are either of the following database models "better"? Is there a con to using the first model (performance, etc.), which clearly easier to setup. I imagine the only con is the pickle type isn't clear what we are storing.

Note this web app is growing every month so I prefer a flexible database model. I know `MongoDB` would probably be a better choice here but everything is already written with SQL and I don't want to rewrite the entire app.

Comment: What DBMS is used for this application?

Comment: Either postgres or sqlite

Comment: the thing is that postgres supports very effective json storing and indexing, can you rely on its specific functionality?

Comment: Note sure what your asking...so you're saying postgres should perform well with the pickletype model?

Comment: No, my point is that with postgres you can use the third model, not mentioned in the post - store json in `data` field instead of pickle

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko good to know thanks!